# Element in a JSON file with different format

Tags: c#, json

i have json file with elements given below.

```
"Format": "AA00;{0:X}",
"Format": "AA00;{0:+000;-000;+000},{1:+000;-000;+000}",
"Format": "AA03;{0:+00;-00;+00},{1:+00;-00;+00}",
"Format": "AA04;{0:00}",
"Format": "AD01;{0:0}",
"Format": "AB01;{0}",
"Format": "AB03;{0:0000}",
"Format": "AC03;{0,0:X2},{1,0:X2},{2,0:X2}",
"Format": "AO04;{0:0}{1}",
"Format": "AW09;{0:000},{1:000},{2:000},{3:000}",
```

can anyone please explain me what does it means?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what are you trying to do?

Comment: This isn't strictly a valid JSON format. You have multiple `format` properties which will override.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't strictly a valid JSON format. You have multiple `Format` properties which will override.

http://jsfiddle.net/otj7eh0o/

In terms of the values for `Format`, this isn't JSON related, but is more likely used as string formatting in another method.

It looks similar to C# `string.format`